# Request Folder ID by name from specific folder: Google Shared Drive

Tags: c#, google-api

I am currently endeavoring to retrieve the ID of a child folder within a Google Shared Drive, based on the name of said child folder. To achieve this, it is imperative that I set the parent folder ID to exclusively search within the designated directory.

For instance, my objective is to obtain the ID (as a string) of the folder named "Testing," situated within the "HQ3rtyPP" Directory ID.

I have already developed the following code to accomplish this task. However, I have encountered an issue wherein the result consistently returns null. Despite conducting thorough verification to ensure the existence of the test folder I am searching for, I am unable to identify the root cause of this problem.

```
public string GetFolderIdByName(string parentFolderId, string folderName)
{
    // Define the search query to look for folders with the specified name within the parent folder
    string query = $"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '{parentFolderId}' in parents and name = '{folderName}' and trashed = false";

    // Define fields to retrieve only the ID of the found folder
    FilesResource.ListRequest request = driveService.Files.List();
    request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
    request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
    request.Fields = "files(id)";
    request.Q = query;

    // Execute the search and retrieve the results
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = request.Execute().Files;

    // Check if the folder was found
    if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
    {
        // Return the ID of the first folder found (there should be only one folder with that name)
        return files[0].Id;
    }

    // Folder not found
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following needed to be added to the `request` as I am accessing this from a shared drive:

```
request.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
```

All working now as intended.